Two equivalent definitions of function?
I am studying Kenneth Kunen's The Foundations of Mathematics, where the definition of a function is given as $$
\forall x\in\mathrm{dom} (R)\,\exists! y\,[\langle x,y\rangle \in R]\tag{1}
$$
I also came across a second definition
$$
\forall x\,\forall y\,\forall y'\,[\langle x,y\rangle \in R \land\langle x,y'\rangle \in R]\Rightarrow [y=y']\tag{2}
$$
Both definitions seem correct, but I am unsure how to prove that the two definitions are equivalent. I tried to expand on (1)
$$
\forall x\, [\exists z\,\langle x,z\rangle\in R]\Rightarrow [\exists y\,(\langle x,y\rangle\in R)\land(\forall y'\langle x,y'\rangle\in R\Rightarrow y=y')]
\tag{1'}
$$
but then I got stuck, I don't know how to transform $\exists y$ into $\forall y$. In the above passage, $\langle a,b\rangle$ is an abbreviation of $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, and $R$ is a relation.

Yes, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent.
First, observe that $(1)$ can be rephrased as
$$
\forall x (x \in \text{dom}(R) \Rightarrow \exists ! y \, \langle x,y \rangle \in R)
$$
that is, since $x\in \text{dom}(R)$ means $\exists z\, \langle x,z\rangle \in R$,
$$
\forall x\, \Big(\exists z\,\langle x,z\rangle\in R \Rightarrow \exists y\,\big (\langle x,y\rangle\in R \land \forall y'(\langle x,y'\rangle\in R\Rightarrow y=y') \big) \Big)
\tag{1'}
$$
which is nothing but $(1')$ in the OP with a slightly different use of the parentheses just to better stress the scope of the quantifiers.
Now, since in general $\big(\exists z A(z) \big) \Rightarrow B$ with $z$ not occurring in $B$ is equivalent to $\forall z (A(z) \Rightarrow B)$, we have that $(1')$ is equivalent to
$$
\forall x\, \forall z \, \Big( \langle x,z\rangle \in R \Rightarrow \exists y\, \big( \langle x,y\rangle\in R \land \forall y' (\langle x,y'\rangle\in R\Rightarrow y=y') \big) \Big)
\tag{3}
$$
which is in turn equivalent to
$$
\forall x\, \forall z \, \Big( \langle x,z\rangle \in R  \Rightarrow \forall y' (\langle x,y'\rangle\in R\Rightarrow z=y') \Big)
\tag{4}
$$
and $(4)$ is equivalent to $(2)$ in the OP (just replace $z$ with $y$), since in general $A \Rightarrow \forall y' B(y')$ with $y'$ not occurring in $A$ is equivalent to $\forall y' (A \Rightarrow B(y'))$, and $A \Rightarrow (B \Rightarrow C)$ is equivalent to $(A \land B) \Rightarrow C$.

I see what you mean! By repeatedly using $A\Rightarrow B=\lnot A\lor B$, we can convert $\exists$ to $\forall$. Regarding $[\forall x, A(x)]\land B=\forall x, [A(x)\land B]$ and $[\forall x, A(x)]\lor B=\forall x, [A(x)\lor B]$ with  not occurring in , is this a logical axiom or a theorem?

@user1361001 - Concerning the first part of your comment, yes, you got it!

@user1361001 - As for the second part (axiom or theorem), it depends on your viewpoint. I'd say that logical equivalences are consequences of how the semantics of connectives and quantifiers is defined in classical logic (take the definition of a model of a first-order formula in any textbook). These logical equivalences can also be derived syntactically in a proof system with some axioms and inference rules, e.g. Hilbert calculus. The semantic and the syntactic approaches are equivalent thanks to the completeness theorem.

Thanks! I have one more small question. When I convert $\exists z$ in (1') to $\forall z$, I can prove through the meaning of quantifiers that it is equivalent to (4). However, how did you change $\land$ inside the second-level brackets in (1') to $\Rightarrow$, and then get (3) and subsequently (4)? I couldn't quite understand that part. Is there a standard method for deriving this?

That's a mistake. The $\land$ should not have become $\Rightarrow$ there. What you actually need to do is project out the second conjunct from the $\land$, use it twice (once with $z$ and once with $y'$), and apply transitivity of equality as in my answer.

@user1361001 - There was a typo in $(3)$ (now it's fixed): the connective just before $\forall y'$ is $\land$, not $\Rightarrow$, and this is crucial, otherwise the equivalence between $(1')$ and $(3)$ is lost. The equivalence between $(3)$ and $(4)$ is more delicate: it's obvious that $(4)$ implies $(3)$. The fact that $(3)$ implies $(4)$ follows from the specific meaning of $(3)$: indeed, $(3)$ says that if $x$ is in relation with $z$, then there is a unique $y$ related to $x$. This implies that such a $y$ should be in particular $z$, hence $(4)$.

The second definition says that $R$ is a functional relation, but doesn't imply that $R$ is total, so the two definitions aren't equivalent, although of course (1) implies (2).
The correct translation of (1) is
$$\forall x. \exists y. \langle x, y \rangle \in R \land \forall y'. \langle x, y' \rangle \in R \to y = y'$$
So in particular using the right conjunct twice you can prove that $$\forall x\ y'\ y''. \langle x, y' \rangle \in R \land \langle x, y'' \rangle \in R \to y' = y = y''$$

I strongly disagree with what you said about $(1)$: that formula doesn't say that $R$ is total, indeed it can be rewritten as $\forall x (x \in \text{dom}(R) \rightarrow \exists ! y , \langle x,y \rangle \in R)$. According to that book, a function is defined as the graph of a functional relation, its domain is defined ``a posteriori''. Concerning the OP, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent indeed (see my answer below).

@Taroccoesbrocco recall that $R$ is total (or entire) if every element of the domain is related to at least one element of the codomain, i.e. $\forall x \in \mathrm{dom}(R). \exists y. \langle x, y \rangle \in R$. Unique existence ($\exists!$) implies existence ($\exists$), so (1) implies that $R$ is total.

Oh, I see what you mean. Defining the domain a posteriori is definitely a strange thing to do, but in that case (1) and (2) are indeed equivalent.

To make these two definitions equivalent, you have to explicitly define
$$\mathrm{dom}(R)=\{x\,:\,\exists y\,(\langle x,y \rangle \in R)\}$$
